# Can't access files on Windows D drive after installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

While installing Ubuntu, I clicked on "delete and install Ubuntu only" (something like that).

I thought it would clear all the files in C and install Ubuntu. But I can't access my files on D drive. Were they deleted during the installation? If not, how can I access them?

Comment: Is the D drive actually a separate drive or just a separate partition? If you're not sure, boot an Ubuntu live cd/usb, run the command `sudo parted -l` in a terminal, and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

Windows lies about what drives are. It's likely that what you thought was your D drive was actually a separate partition on the same hard drive, so by telling Ubuntu to wipe your hard drive, it was wiped as well.

Answer (score 1):

If c: and d: drives are separate physical drives then you may simply need to look at mounting the drive in order to access it's contents.

Open a Terminal window:

```
sudo fdisk --list
```

This will display results such as:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d50ad

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 960522239 960520192  458G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       960524286 976771071  16246786  7.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       960524288 976771071  16246784  7.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Each different physical drive will show as /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, and so forth.

Note the differences: /sd**a**, /sd**b** - these represent your physical drives.

so if the d: drive is /dev/sdb. Create a directory to mount the drive, example below:

So if your d: drive is ntfs, the following may apply:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ntfs-3g
sudo mkdir /myddrive
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /myddrive
```

If you want to have it available when the system starts up:
https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/mount-ntfs-partition-or-drive-at-startup-with-user-as-owner-in-ubuntu-linux

Comment: Why "-t smbfs"? That's for network filesystems.